# How can $V(k)-V(r)=O_p(C_{NT}^{-2})$ imply $V(k)/V(r)=1 + O_p(C_{NT}^{-2})$, where $C_{NT}=\min \{ \sqrt{N} , \sqrt{T} \}$?

Tags: categorical-data, econometrics, asymptotics

I am reading [Bai and Ng (2002)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1468-0262.00273). In their proof of Corollary 1, they said “Next, consider k > r. Lemma 4 implies that $V(k)/V(r)=1 + O_p(C_{NT}^{-2})$”. However, Lemma 4 just states that $V(k)-V(r)=O_p(C_{NT}^{-2})$. Is there something wrong?

As a counterexample, if $V(k)\sim C_{NT}^{-2}$ and $V(r) \sim C_{NT}^{-3}$, then $V(k)/V(r)$ will not converge in probability to $1$.

How does the deduction in the paper make sense?

Comment: This is a "Big O" probabilistic statement (stochastically bounded), not convergence in probability (little o in probability).

Comment: I've removed tag factor analysis because the question is about a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing the paper, let $\min SSR$ denote the minimized Sum of Panel Squared Residuals of something that is estimated in there. Then
$$V(k) = \frac 1 {NT} \min SSR.$$

and (I guess) analogously for $V(r)$.

Now, $V(k)-V(r)=O_p(C_{NT}^{-2})$ means, that after some sample size threshold,

$$\exists\,  0<M<\infty:\Pr \left(\left|\frac{V(k)-V(r)}{C_{NT}^{-2}}\right| > M \right) < \epsilon,\quad \forall\, \epsilon >0. $$

It would appear that $V(k) > V(r)>0$. Then
$$\Pr \left(\left|\frac{V(k)-V(r)}{C_{NT}^{-2}}\right| > M \right) =\Pr \left(V(k) > V(r) + \frac{M}{C_{NT}^{2}} \right) $$

$$ = \Pr \left(\frac{V(k)}{V(r)} > 1 + \frac{M}{V(r) \cdot C_{NT}^{2}} \right). $$

Now,
$$\frac{M}{V(r) \cdot C_{NT}^{2}} = \frac {M}{\frac 1 {TN} \min SSR \cdot [\min(N,T)]} = \frac{\max (T,N)\cdot M}{\min SSR}.$$

The authors claim that this term we arrived at is also $O_p(C_{NT}^{-2})$, namely they claim that after some size threshold, (no need for absolute values)

$$\exists\,  0<M_1<\infty:\Pr \left(\frac{\max (T,N)\cdot M}{\min SSR\cdot C_{NT}^{-2}} > M_1\right) < \epsilon_1,\quad \forall\, \epsilon_1 >0. $$

We have
$$\frac{\max (T,N)\cdot M}{\min SSR\cdot C_{NT}^{-2}} = \frac{\max (T,N)\cdot \min (T,N)\cdot M}{\min SSR} = \frac{NT\cdot M}{\min SSR}=\frac{M}{V(r)}.$$

So the authors' claim is that, at worst after some size threshold we have

$$\exists\,  0<M_1<\infty:\Pr \left(\frac{M}{V(r)} > M_1\right) = \Pr \left(V(r) < \frac{M}{M_1} \right) < \epsilon_1, \quad \forall\, \epsilon_1 >0. $$

This last probability is equivalent to the Distribution Function of the non-negative $V(r)$ (if the latter is continuous), evaluated at $M/M_1$. Given any $M$ (that comes from their previous assertion), we need only to find some arbitrarily larger and larger $M_1$. By making $M_1$ large enough the value $M/M_1$ becomes arbitrarily small, tending to zero, for which the value of this distribution function is zero, and so the claim holds.

Comment: Why $\mathrm{Pr}(V(r) < C)$ can be arbitrarily small? The only condition we have is $V(r) \geq 0$. How to compute $\mathrm{Pr}(V(r)>0)$?

Comment: @Puyi Exactly because $V(r)$ is non-negative, if your $C$ tends to zero, then the probability that $V(r)$ will be smaller than $C$ tends to zero. And we can make $C$ essentially zero by choosing an $M_1$ large enough.